# Pygame fill and blit does not edit screen

Tags: python, pygame

I'm getting familiar with `Pygame` and I want to write a simple game, I already have following code:

```
import sys, pygame
pygame.init()

size = width, height = 640, 480
speed = [2, 2]
black = 0, 0, 0

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

ball = pygame.image.load("intro_ball.gif")
ballrect = ball.get_rect()

bar = pygame.image.load("bar_low.gif")
barrect = bar.get_rect(center=(320,475))

over = pygame.image.load("game_over.gif")
overrect = over.get_rect(center=(width/2, height/2 ))

while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                screen.fill(black)
                screen.blit(over, overrect)
                pygame.display.flip()
                pygame.time.delay(2000)


    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and barrect.right < width:
        barrect = barrect.move(4, 0)
        screen.blit(bar, barrect)
        pygame.display.update()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and barrect.left > 0:
        barrect = barrect.move(-4, 0)
        screen.blit(bar, barrect)
        pygame.display.update()
    ballrect = ballrect.move(speed)
    if ballrect.left < 0 or ballrect.right > width:
        speed[0] = -speed[0]
    if ballrect.top < 0 or (ballrect.bottom > height - bar.get_height() and ballrect.left < barrect.right and ballrect.right > barrect.left):
        speed[1] = -speed[1]
    if ballrect.bottom > height:
        #irrelevant


    screen.fill(black)
    screen.blit(ball, ballrect)
    screen.blit(bar, barrect)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

It works fine apart the "if '`w`' is pressed" part: what it should do is to fill black, show the "`game_over`" image for two seconds and continue to work. Instead of this it freezes everything for two seconds and continues to work, like the following lines never existed.

```
screen.fill(black)
screen.blit(over, overrect)
pygame.display.flip()
```

Could you tell what do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The positions of the bar (`barrect`), the the position of the ball (`ballrect`) and the speed (`speed`) have to be set to the initial state, when the game is restarted:

Create an function which initializes the game states:

```py
def InitGame():
    global ballrect, barrect, speed
    speed = [2, 2]
    ballrect = ball.get_rect()
    barrect = bar.get_rect(center=(320,475))
```

Call it once at startup:

```py
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

ball = pygame.image.load("intro_ball.gif")
bar = pygame.image.load("bar_low.gif")
over = pygame.image.load("game_over.gif")
overrect = over.get_rect(center=(width/2, height/2 ))

InitGame();
```

Call it again when the game has to be restarted.
I recommend not to delay the game by [`pygame.time.delay()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.delay). Calculate the time when the game has to be restarted `starttime`. Draw either the game screen or the "game over" screen dependent on the time:

```py
starttime = 0
while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:

                # reset game and init the new start time
                InitGame()
                starttime = pygame.time.get_ticks() + 2000

    if pygame.time.get_ticks() > starttime: 

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        # [...]

        screen.fill(black)
        screen.blit(ball, ballrect)
        screen.blit(bar, barrect)

    else:

        screen.fill(black)
        screen.blit(over, overrect)

    pygame.display.flip()
```